# I have created a voice assistant but i want to convert this assistant language to Hindi please help me

Tags: python

```
 import pyttsx3
 import speech_recognition as sr
 import datetime
 import wikipedia
 import webbrowser
 import os
 import googlesearch
 import smtplib
 import playsound
 from gtts import gTTS
 import wolframalpha
 from selenium import webdriver
 import pyaudio
 import urllib3
 import random
 from time import strftime
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
 import re
 import subprocess
 from googletrans import Translator

 engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
 voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
 engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
 def speak(audio):
     engine.say(audio)
     engine.runAndWait()
 def wishMe():
     hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
     if hour>=0 and hour<12:
         speak("Good Morning!")
     elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
         speak("Good Afternoon!")
     else:
        speak("Good Evening!")
 def takeCommand():
     r = sr.Recognizer()
     with sr.Microphone() as source:
         print("Listening...")
         r.pause_threshold = 1
         audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=5)
     try:
         print("Recognizing...")
         query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
         print(f"User said: {query}\n")

     except Exception as e:
         # print(e)
         print("Say that again please...")
         return "None"
     return query
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     wishMe()
     while True:
         query = takeCommand().lower()
         if 'information' in query:
             speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
             query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
             results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=10)
             translator = Translator()
             result = translator.translate(results, dest='hi')
             speak("According to Wikipedia")
             print(result)
             speak(result)
```

It prints information in Hindi but does not speak.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the language property using setProperty

```
import pyttsx3
a = pyttsx3.init()
#If this doesn't work try "languages".
a.setProperty("language",'hi')
a.say(text)
a.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Google tts is also really good and supports Hindi. for wavenet voices, you get 1 million free characters a month, for basic voices you get 4 million.